# How to configure upload folder for flask Blueprint()?

Tags: python, flask, filepath

I want to manage to upload and save files into ./project/client/static but whenever I tried to save the file it always end up at ./project/server/.

I want to configure the default upload folder to be ./project/client/static or a temporary folder.

```py
# project/server/main/views.py

@main_blueprint.route("/tasks", methods=["POST"])
def run_task():
    file = request.files.get('file')
    if file.filename == '':
        flash('No selected file')
        return redirect(request.url)
    print('downloading', file.filename)
    filename = file.filename
    file = request.files.get('file')
    filepath = filename
    print('downloading file', filename)
    file.save(filepath)
    print('download complete')
    print('starting task to predict file')
    info = { 'file': filepath }
    task = create_task.delay(info)
    print(task.id)
    return jsonify({"task_id": task.id}), 200
```

This always lead the downloaded file to be saved to ./project/server

I am also using flask Blueprint

```py
# project/server/main/views.py
import os
from flask import render_template, Blueprint, jsonify, request, Response, send_file, redirect, url_for
from celery.result import AsyncResult
from project.server.tasks import create_task
from project.machine_learning import app as machine_learning
main_blueprint = Blueprint("main", __name__, static_folder='static')
upload_folder = './project/client/static/'
```

file structure

```
| - root
  | - readme_files
  | - project
  |  | - machine_learning
  |  |  | - labelled_comments
  |  |  | - models
  |  |  | - notebooks
  |  |  | - src
  |  |  |  | - text_preprocessing
  |  |  |  | - csv_file_modifier
  |  |  |  |  | - pyunittest
  |  |  |  | - keyword_filter
  |  |  |  |  | - pyunittest
  |  |  |  |  |  | - keyword-dictionaries
  |  |  |  |  | - keyword-dictionaries
  |  | - tests
  |  | - server
  |  |  | - main
  |  | - client
  |  |  | - static
  |  |  |  | - archive
  |  |  | - templates
```

Answer (score 3):

You can specify that the file should be saved in `upload_folder`. The approach I would take is to add an environment variable that defines the path to the upload folder.

```py
# .env file
UPLOAD_PATH=project/client/static/
```

Then, set up a configuration to access `UPLOAD_PATH`:

```py
# config.py

import os

class Config(object):
    UPLOAD_PATH = os.environ.get("UPLOAD_PATH")
```

The extension `python-dotenv` will be useful here, so install it. Load this configuration in your application's instance(where you have defined `app`):

```py
# __init__.py

from config import Config

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
```

Update the `save()` function in your routes as follows:

```py
import os


@main_blueprint.route("/tasks", methods=["POST"])
def run_task():
   # ...
   file.save(os.path.join(app.config["UPLOAD_PATH"], filepath)
# ...
```